# How to deploy 'develop' branch using GIT's hooks?

Tags: git, deployment, githooks, git-bash

Hi was following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps) tutorial to make in my server a git hook which 'copies' the source files from repo to another directory.

This is the `post-receive` hook and works great:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/domain.com --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f
```

But I need to 'copy' files from my develop branch not from master. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the branch name at the end.

`git --work-tree=/var/www/domain.com --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout develop -f`